# Populate Select Dropdown Using Knockout from Data Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Populating simple dropdown list with items from the data model using Knockout.js

```
<select name="selectCourseArea" class="form-control" data-bind="value: typeid"></select>
```

At this point I am just attempting to get anything from the database into the dropdown without success. I am not the original author of the code, so I am trying to understand what is going on without any prior knowledge or use of knockout. Where would I need to load the DB information from the model to the controller. How does it get to the Knockout code to go to the view?

```
var CourseViewModel = function (courseIn) {
var self = this;
if (courseIn === undefined) {
    courseIn = {};
}

self.id = courseIn.Id;
self.name = ko.observable(courseIn.Name);
self.postalCode = ko.observable(courseIn.PostalCode);
self.city = ko.observable(courseIn.City);
self.province = ko.observable(courseIn.Province);
self.courseId = ko.observable(courseIn.CourseId);
self.courseAreas = ko.observableArray();

$.each(courseIn.CourseAreas, function(index, courseArea) {
    self.courseAreas.push(new CourseAreaViewModel(courseArea));
});

self.newCourseArea = function () {
    var newArea = true;
    $.each(self.courseAreas(), function (index, obj) {
        console.log(obj.name());
        if ((obj.name() === undefined || obj.name() === null) || (obj.acreage() === null || obj.acreage() === 0)) {
            newArea = false;
        }
    });

    console.log(newArea);
    if (newArea) {
        $.ajax("/CourseArea/Add", {
            data: {
                courseId: self.id
            },
            dataType: "json",
            method: "post"
        }).done(function(newCourseArea) {
            console.log(newCourseArea);
            self.courseAreas.push(new CourseAreaViewModel(newCourseArea));
        });
    } else {
        alert("Please fill in the course area name and acreage before adding another!");
    }

}

self.deleteCourseArea = function (courseArea) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this course area?")) {
        $.ajax("/CourseArea/Delete/" + courseArea.id, {
            method: "post",
            dataType:"json"
        }).done(function (feedback) {
            if (feedback.Success) {
                self.courseAreas.remove(courseArea);
            }
            alert(feedback.Message);
        });
    }
}
}

var CourseAreaViewModel = function(courseAreaIn) {
var self = this;
if (courseAreaIn === undefined) {
    courseAreaIn = {};
}
self.id = courseAreaIn.Id;
self.name = ko.observable(courseAreaIn.Name);
self.acreage = ko.observable(courseAreaIn.Acreage);
self.goals = ko.observable(courseAreaIn.Goals);
self.typeid = ko.observableArray(courseAreaIn.typeid);
}
```

Comment: this site would probably be a better place to ask http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll keep that in mind as other replys come in(or don't)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to bind `courseAreas` to the options of the select, and since it is made up of objects, you need to specify keys for the text and value components:

```
<select name="selectCourseArea" class="form-control" data-bind="options: courseAreas, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: typeid"></select>
```